# Estancado código de una tienda

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo este ejercicio para completar, eh hecho lo que pude, recién estoy aprendiendo acerca de la programación orientada a objetos, solo me faltan algunos métodos por completar que no pude como el de mostrar un producto llamándolo por su nombre o los últimos, si me podrían ayudar por favor se los agradecería.

```
public class Tienda {

    private Producto[] lista;
    private int contador = 0;

    public Tienda(int tamaño) {
        lista = new Producto[tamaño];
    }

    public void agregarProducto(Producto p) {
        lista[contador] = p;
        contador++;
    }

    public void agregarProducto(String nombre, String categoria, float precio) {
        Producto nuevo = new Producto(nombre, categoria, precio);

    }

    public String verProducto(int pos) {
        Producto aux = lista[pos];
        return aux.getNombre() + " -- " + aux.getPrecio();
    }

    public String verProducto(String nombre) {
        //Mostar el producto por el nombre
    }

    public String verLista() {
        String texto = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {

            Producto aux = lista[i];
            if (aux != null) {
                texto += aux.getInfo() + "\n";

            } else {
                texto += "-- vacio --\n";
            }
        }
        return texto;
    }


    public boolean borarProducto(int pos) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean borrarProducto(String nombre) {
        return false;

    }

    public Producto getProducto(int pos) {
        return null;

    }

    public Producto buscarProducto(String nombre) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

En esta clase van todos los métodos para mostrarlo en una clase main.

Comment: para tu metodo verProducto, recorre tu lista asi como en verLista, y dentro te la validacion aux !=null haz otro if comparando tu parametro nombre.equals(aux.getNombre) y si cumple retornas lo que te piden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tu metodo verProducto, recorre tu lista asi como en verLista, y dentro te la validacion `aux !=null` haz otro if comparando tu parametro `nombre.equals(aux.getNombre())` y si cumple retornas lo que te piden, algo como esto:

```
public String verProducto(String nombre) {
        //Mostar el producto por el nombre
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            Producto aux = lista[i];
            if (aux != null) {
               if(nombre.equals(aux.getNombre())){
                 return aux.getInfo();
               }
            }
         }
         return "no se encontro";
}
```

Para borrar o eliminar un elemento de tu lista tienes que recorrer todos los siguientes elementos y decrementar tu contador:

```
 //si existe la posicion lo borra y devuelve true, caso contrario false
public boolean borarProducto(int pos) {
    if(pos <= contador){
         for (int i = pos; i < lista.length; i++) {
           //a esta posicion traes el siguiente hasta llegar al penultimo
            lista[i] = lista[i+1];
         }
       contador --;
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Aqui de igual forma recorres tu lista con un for comparas con `equals` y una vez que ya sabes la posicion puedes usar el metodo anterior:

```
public boolean borrarProducto(String nombre) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            Producto aux = lista[i];
            if (aux != null) {
               if(nombre.equals(aux.getNombre())){
                 borarProducto(i); //para que reinventar la rueda :)
                 return true;
               }
            }
         }
    return false;
}
```

Accedes directamente, falta validar la posicion, que sea positivo y menor o igual que contador:

```
public Producto getProducto(int pos) {
    return lista[pos];

}
```

Para buscar un producto tienes que comparar usando `equals` que sirve String:

```
public Producto buscarProducto(String nombre) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            Producto aux = lista[i];
            if (aux != null) {
               if(nombre.equals(aux.getNombre())){
                 return lista[pos];
               }
            }
         }
    return null;
}
```

**Nota**: faltan algunas validaciones para la posicion(que este en el rango 0-contador).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvieron de mucho tus comentarios para comprender mejor. Gracias y un saludo